# Meaning of $\sum$ without bounds and variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus, notation

I'm trying to figure out how to solve a problem from putnam 1958 shown in that [video](https://youtu.be/AAir4vcxRPU?t=416)

> A sequence of numbers $\alpha_i \in [0, 1]$ is chosen at random. Show that the expected value of $n$, where $\sum 1^n \space\space \alpha_i>0, \sum 1^{n-1} \space\space \alpha_i \le 1$ is $e$

I'm not sure I understood the whole definition correctly, please check the original in the video above

My question is: What does $\sum 1^n$ even mean? I thought $\sum$ must have start and end range and non-constant value at the right side of it

P.S. I'm not sure I've chosen a correct tag, please fix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not $$\Sigma 1^n\alpha_i$$That's
$$
\Sigma{}_1{}^n\alpha_i
$$
Which is to say
$$
\sum_1^n\alpha_i
$$
They really ought to say $i=1$ rather than just $1$ on the bottom, and they really ought to have the lower and upper aligned with one another horizontally. But there could be typographical limits that stopped them from aligning them. And once you know that the summation goes from $1$ to $n$, there isn't really room for any doubt as to what goes from $1$ to $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The symbols on the [exam](https://prase.cz/kalva/putnam/putn58.html) are $\sum_1^n a_i$ and $\sum_1^{n-1}a_i$.  The $1$ is the lower limit of the sum and $n$ and $n-1$ are the upper limits of the sum.  The summation variable of $i$ is implied.  It is the same as $$\sum_{i=1}^na_i$$

The point is that $n$ is the index value where the running sum exceeds $1$.  You are to show that the expected value of $n$ is $e$.